# How do you check out a subfolder from a bazaar repository?

Tags: bazaar

Is there a way to checkout a single subfolder from a bazaar repository?  In one of my bazaar repositories, the top level hierarchy is

- documents
- sql_schemas
- www

I'd like to be able to just checkout www into public_html on a demo webserver, but I don't see how to do that without doing a checkout in a working directory and then symlinking www in there.

Is there a better way?  I'm new with BZR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most distributed VCS don't support checking out subtrees, because the state of the entire repository is stored instead of just references to another repo.

If you don't need the history in your public_html directory, you can use `export`:

```
$ bzr export /path/to/public_html/www /path/to/repo/www
```